# iPhone: slow down recorded video

Tags: iphone, performance, video

Can anyone explain why this isn't slowing down my video to 5 seconds? secondAsset.duration is equal to 15 seconds. After it is exported it just plays the video for 5 seconds and then shows the last frame for the remaining 10 seconds..

```
AVMutableCompositionTrack *secondTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [secondTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:firstAsset.duration error:nil];

    [secondTrack scaleTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration) toDuration:CMTimeMake(5,1)];
```

Comment: try giving custom duration like below in scaleTimeRange [secondTrack scaleTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,5)) toDuration:CMTimeMake(5,1)];